# How to filter geojson using toggle buttons in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

After loading geojson polygons, I want to implement a toggle menu to filter by a value. I assume the implementation is [similar to this cartodb map which uses SQL statements.](http://erichsen-group.com/demoland/Cartodb/LosAngeles.html)

I image I could use a layer-selector and pass a variable from a menu such as District 1.

My code just brings in and styles a layer of 15 polygons. I want to keep this, but add a filter. How is this done in leaflet? Examples much appreciated.

```
   L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2tvcmFzYXVydXMiLCJhIjoiaEdGTUZWTSJ9.osOC8tWU3bMaNprVNoEu7g';

    var lamap = L.mapbox.map('mapid', 'skorasaurus.5eb85050')
        .setView([34.000880, -118.04036], 10);

    var featLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(lamap);

    featLayer.loadURL('citycouncils.geojson');

    function getMyColor(myargument) {
        if (myargument === '1') {
            return '#996767'
        };
        if (myargument === '2') {
            return '#679967'
        };
        if (myargument === '10') {
            return '#672799'
        };
        if (myargument === '14') {
            return '#670099'
        };
        if (myargument === '15') {
            return '#699799'
        };
    }

    // styles each polygon based on its properties in the geojson file, using leaflet's setStyle
    featLayer.on('ready', function() {
        featLayer.eachLayer(function(polygon) {
            polygon.bindPopup('District ' + polygon.feature.properties.DISTRICT);
            console.log(typeof setStyle);
            polygon.setStyle({
                opacity: 0.55,
                  weight: 2,
                    opacity: 1,
                fillOpacity: 0.55,
                fillColor: getMyColor(polygon.feature.properties.DISTRICT),
                color: 'white'
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: So many ifs. Use an object or array for the lookup.

Comment: I don't see a question, and i see absolutely nothing in your code that has anything to do with filtering, no logic, no inputs, nothing. What did you come up with? What problems did you have? What errors did it give? Please share and show an example of what you tried to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.5/) filtering a `L.mapbox.FeatureLayer` is very simple to do. It's just a matter of setting a filter method using the `setFilter` method of the layer.

Reference of `L.mapbox.FeatureLayer`'s `setFilter` method:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.5/l-mapbox-featurelayer/#section-featurelayer-setfilter

Complete working example is right on the Mapbox site:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/multiple-marker-filters/